# Transitioning to Japanese kanji from Chinese

Tags: learning, chinese

I can read Japanese kanji just fine (being able to read/write Chinese already).
However, I can't seem to remember the pronunciation as the Chinese reading gets in the way. For example, my mind repeatedly reads 食物 as "shi wu" and not *shokumotsu*. Are there any ways of memorizing the correct readings other than simply rote memorization? (To make matters worse I also know Cantonese, so I struggle between 時間 being read as "shi jian", "shi gan", and "jikan").
Anyone been able to overcome this? It's a bit of a roadblock in me learning to read Japanese out loud, especially learning new Japanese terms to speak.

Comment: Have you tried using furigana? It could be helpful for transitioning into the Japanese pronunciations. By the way, I find myself encountering the same problem  in my Chinese studies- using on'yomi readings instead of the actual putonghua reading haha

Comment: Questions about **learning methods** are off-topic because they're not about the Japanese language itself.  See: [We don't do "how do I study X?" questions](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/798/1478).

Comment: This is a problem of "interference", which is something we also discussed on [Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/542/800).

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the Japanese spoken language, one approach you can take is to **rectify each kanji you read with a familiar word that it appears in.**

For example, if you see the kanji 手 and you naturally want to pronounce it "zu" instead of "te," recall that you know that same kanji from the word 手紙, in which it is pronounced "te."